# Can i use source item values in radListView.itemTemplates

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am creating an array of radListView im my page and for each radList, i implement one "radListView.itemTemplates" as follow:

```
radListView.itemTemplates = [
                {
                    key: "notaBaixa",
                    createView: () => {
                        const gridLayout = new GridLayout();

                        gridLayout.addColumn(new ItemSpec(1, GridUnitType.STAR));
                        gridLayout.addColumn(new ItemSpec(1, GridUnitType.AUTO));
                        gridLayout.addColumn(new ItemSpec(1, GridUnitType.AUTO));
                        gridLayout.verticalAlignment = "middle";
                        gridLayout.css = "border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:black;";

                        const lblDisciplina = new Label();
                        lblDisciplina.col = 0;
                        lblDisciplina.setInlineStyle("padding:10px 0 0 10px; height:60px;");
                        lblDisciplina.verticalAlignment = "middle";
                        lblDisciplina.text = "{{disciplina}}";

                        const lblnotaTotal = new Label();
                        lblnotaTotal.col = 1;
                        lblnotaTotal.setInlineStyle("padding:10px 0 0 10px; height:60px; color: red;");
                        lblnotaTotal.verticalAlignment = "middle";
                        lblnotaTotal.text = "{{nota_total}}";

                        const lblFaltasTotal = new Label();
                        lblFaltasTotal.col = 2;
                        lblFaltasTotal.setInlineStyle("padding:10px 0 0 10px; height:60px;");
                        lblFaltasTotal.verticalAlignment = "middle";
                        lblFaltasTotal.text = "{{faltas_total}}";

                        gridLayout.addChild(lblDisciplina);
                        gridLayout.addChild(lblnotaTotal);
                        gridLayout.addChild(lblFaltasTotal);

                        return gridLayout;
                    }
                },
                {
                    key: "notaAlta",
                    createView: () => {
                        const gridLayout = new GridLayout();
                        gridLayout.addColumn(new ItemSpec(1, GridUnitType.STAR));
                        gridLayout.addColumn(new ItemSpec(1, GridUnitType.AUTO));
                        gridLayout.addColumn(new ItemSpec(1, GridUnitType.AUTO));
                        gridLayout.verticalAlignment = "middle";
                        gridLayout.css = "border-bottom-width:1px; border-bottom-color:black;";

                        const lblDisciplina = new Label();
                        lblDisciplina.col = 0;
                        lblDisciplina.setInlineStyle("padding:10px 0 0 10px; height:60px;");
                        lblDisciplina.verticalAlignment = "middle";
                        lblDisciplina.text = "{{disciplina}}";

                        const lblnotaTotal = new Label();
                        lblnotaTotal.col = 1;
                        lblnotaTotal.setInlineStyle("padding:10px 0 0 10px; height:60px; color: blue;");
                        lblnotaTotal.verticalAlignment = "middle";
                        lblnotaTotal.text = "{{nota_total}}";

                        const lblFaltasTotal = new Label();
                        lblFaltasTotal.col = 2;
                        lblFaltasTotal.setInlineStyle("padding:10px 0 0 10px; height:60px;");
                        lblFaltasTotal.verticalAlignment = "middle";
                        lblFaltasTotal.text = "{{faltas_total}}";

                        gridLayout.addChild(lblDisciplina);
                        gridLayout.addChild(lblnotaTotal);
                        gridLayout.addChild(lblFaltasTotal);

                        return gridLayout;
                    }
                }
            ];
```

As you can see, in my label i am trying get some property of source item but the label does not understand as property. how can i set the label text value as item source property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the [data binding docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding). The syntax you are using, is only valid on XML, the XML parser will interpret the syntax and initiate binding between the element and data model.

You have to call `bind` method on the target element and pass the source & target property to do the same programatically.

For example,

```
lblDisciplina.text = "{{disciplina}}";
```

Should be

```
lblDisciplina.bind({
   sourceProperty: "disciplina",
   targetProperty: "text",
   twoWay: false
});
```

Comment: thanks @Manoj 
I read RadListView documentation and  there's nothing about .bind() to use with itemTemplates.

Comment: Bind is a method on View, it doesn't have to be with RasListView docs.